# Not able to get correct position of element when clicking via tab key

Tags: javascript, html

I am getting the correct position of the element if I click using mouse, but not able to get if click through tab key.

To reproduce the behavior, focus on the element using tab and press Enter.

```js
var linkElement = document.getElementById('link');
linkElement.addEventListener('click', function(e){
  console.log(e.clientX, e.clientY);
});
```

```css
#link{
  position: absolute;
  top: 5%;
  left: 15%;
}
#placeholder{
  display: none;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
}
```

```html
<a href="javascript:void(0)" id="link">
LINK
</a>

<div id="placeholder">
  PLACEHOLDER
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that clientX and clientY is only for the mouse according to [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MouseEvent/clientX).

What I would do is to return the coords of the center on tab by the offset properties (when the clientX and the clientY are 0,0):

```js
var linkElement = document.getElementById('link');
linkElement.addEventListener('click', function(e){
  if (e.clientX > 0 && e.clientY > 0) {
      console.log(e.clientX, e.clientY);
  } else {
      console.log(this.offsetLeft + (this.offsetWidth / 2), this.offsetTop + (this.offsetHeight / 2));
  }
});
```

```css
#link{
  position: absolute;
  top: 5%;
  left: 15%;
}
#placeholder{
  display: none;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
}
```

```html
<a href="javascript:void(0)" id="link">
LINK
</a>

<div id="placeholder">
  PLACEHOLDER
</div>
```

**UPDATE:**

Or with getBoundingRect as epascarello suggested:

```js
var linkElement = document.getElementById('link');
linkElement.addEventListener('click', function(e){
  if (e.clientX > 0 && e.clientY > 0) {
      console.log(e.clientX, e.clientY);
  } else {
      var boundingRect = this.getBoundingClientRect();
      console.log(Math.round(boundingRect.x + (boundingRect.width / 2)), Math.round(boundingRect.y + (boundingRect.height / 2)));
  }
});
```

```css
#link{
  position: absolute;
  top: 5%;
  left: 15%;
}
#placeholder{
  display: none;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
}
```

```html
<a href="javascript:void(0)" id="link">
LINK
</a>

<div id="placeholder">
  PLACEHOLDER
</div>
```

Comment: This code prints '117 19' which is its center as you can see in the console when selecting it via tab.

Comment: [getBoundingClientRect](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getBoundingClientRect) is another way

Comment: @epascarello you are right, I've just added another implementation this time with getBoundingClientRect() as you suggested and the same result `117 19`

Comment: I used getBoundingClientRect as a fallback.